# Python 'BeautiulSoup()' function what does it actually do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Python nube here. I know two methods to parse URL to BeautifulSoup to open URLs.

Method #1 USING REQUESTS

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests   
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print soup.prettify()
```

Method #2 USING URLLIB/URLLIB2

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page = f.read() #Some people skip this step.
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print soup.prettify()
```

I have following questions:

1. What exactly does BeautifulSoup() function does ? Somewhere it requires `page.content` and `html.parser` and somewhere it only takes `urllib2.urlopen(url).read` (as stated in the second example). This is very simple to cram but hard to understand what is going on here. I have checked the official documentation, not very helpful. (Please also comment on `html.parser` and `page.content`, why not just html and page like in second example ?)
2. In Method#2 as stated above, what difference does it make if I skip the `f.read()` command ?

For experts, these questions might be very simple, but I would really appreciate help on these. I have googled quite a lot but still not getting the answers. 
Thanks !

Comment: 1. You might want to read the docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup 2. It will not work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` is a python package to help you parse html.

The first argument it requires is just a raw html response, or any raw html or xml text that it can parse, so it doesn't matter what package delivers that as long as it is in valid html format.

The second argument, in your first example `html.parser` is telling BeautifulSoup what package to use to actually parse the data. In my knowledge there are only 2 options, `html.parser` and `lxml`. They do the same basically but with different performance advantages, that's the only difference as far as I can tell.

If you omit that second argument then the BeautifulSoup package just uses the default, which is `lxml` in most cases.

To your last question i'm not entirely sure, but I think there is no fundamental difference between invoking `f.read()` first or having BeautifulSoup do that implicitly but that would not always work and is bad practice.

Like @Klaus said in a comment to you, you should really read [the docs here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup)

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup does not open URLs. It takes HTML, and gives you the ability to prettify the output (as you have done).

In both method #1 and #2 you are fetching the HTML using another libary (either requests, or urllib) and then presenting the resulting HTML to beautiful soup.

This is why you need to read the content in method #2.

Therefore, I think you are looking in the wrong spots for documentation. You should be searching how to use request or urllib (I recommend requests myself).